# How to get Django template's JavaScript's session in Django view?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-sessions

I ran `test` view below (The 1st run):

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Then, I could set and get session in `<script></script>` in `index.html` as shown below (The 1st run):

```
{% "templates/index.html" %}

<script>
sessionStorage.setItem("test", "Hello");
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('test')) // Hello
</script>
```

Next, I ran `test` view again with [request.session.get('test')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get) but I could not get the session as shown below (The 2nd run):

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):
    print(request.session.get('test')) # None
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Actually, I could get a Django template's JavaScript's cookie in `test` view.

So, how can I get the Django template's JavaScript's session in `test` view?

Comment: Session data is managed server side. You can not alter session data with your frontend without a request to your server (e.g. with ajax).